# How to turn a result set into a CSV string in subquery in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

Let's say I have this data in the `Customers` table:

```
Id,Name
1,John
2,David
3,Sophia
```

I want to select this data such that the result would be this way:

```
NamesCsv
John,David,Sophia
```

In SQL Server, I would write:

```
select 
(
    select [Name] + ','
    from Customers
    for xml path('')
) as NamesCsv
```

How can I do it in MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` concatenates rows into a single field with the limitation that result will not contain NULL values.

1. With duplicates:

`select group_concat(name) as NamesCsv from Customers;`

2. Without duplicates:

`select group_concat(distinct name) as Namescsv from Customers;`